# How to read all data at once from text file in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, filereader

I have a file "SyncData.txt",

I want to read all data from "SyncData.txt" and send it all at once in Json post request.

Please let me know any solution.

Thanks

Comment: Add more details, like what are the source and destinations of the json calls? What is the structure of data in the txt file? Where's it stored?

Answer (score 0):

Use [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function right in HTTP Request Sampler Body like:

[image: FileToString]

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series for comprehensive information on this and other JMeter Functions.

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for your reply, I tried using same method but its not working